# Mongod , mongosh, mongo. None of these commands are working in M1chip mac

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Can someone help me with MongoDB in m1 chip mac?
I followed every step in tutorials, documentation. I thought running mogosh will finally run it but it says;

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 62e6aed6da3614f1849508af
Connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

and when i try to start mongodb using mongod, it says:
`zsh: command not found: mongod`
and i also tried:
`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"` but this also didn't work.

I'm dealing with it for 4 days, even formatted my pc but nothing worked.

It'd be nice of you if you could help.

Comment: does this path `:/usr/local/mongodb/bin` actually exist? What is the content inside?

Comment: Your question has no details on what steps you followed or the results of those steps. `ECONNREFUSED` means that there is no process listening on port 27017.

Comment: steps I followed
xcode-select --install

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/aashishpanthi/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community@5.0

brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@5.0

mongod
zsh: command not found: mongod

 brew install mongosh

Comment: Edit your question with those details. This guide might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask